# Not being able to json_decode

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am posting data from Vb.net client to a PHP rest api but for some reason the json_decode is not working on the passed string.
The code to post to the server is :

```vb
        Dim payload As String = "{""key"":""Test"",""bookings"":" & txtUpload.Text & "}"

        Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(String.Format(baseAPIImportUrl))
        ' Set the Method property of the request to POST.  
        request.Method = "POST"
        ' Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.  
        Dim byteArray() As Byte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload)
        ' Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.  
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        ' Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.  
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
        ' Get the request stream.  
        Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream
        ' Write the data to the request stream.  
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
        ' Close the Stream object.  
        dataStream.Close()
        ' Get the response.  
        Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse
        ' Display the status.  
        MessageBox.Show(CType(response, HttpWebResponse).StatusDescription)
        ' Get the stream containing content returned by the server.  
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream
        ' Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.  
        Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(dataStream)
        ' Read the content.  
        Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd
        ' Display the content.  
        ' Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer)
        MessageBox.Show(responseFromServer)
        ' Clean up the streams.  
        reader.Close()
        dataStream.Close()
        response.Close()
```

The values  that are being passed :

```
{"key":"91a1522Test",
 "bookings":
   {"booking":[{"ClassId":"4",  "ClassName":"THOASC",   "YearWeek":"1751"}]} }
```

On the PHP side I do :

```php
$bookings = $_POST->bookings
$data = json_decode($bookings,true);
$total = count($data['booking']);
```

The $total should show 1 as there is 1 item in the booking array but it always is shows 0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$_POST->bookings` - this is your problem. `->` is the object access operator, but in PHP, `$_POST` is not an object but an array.

If you were submitting this value as part of form data, you would normally access it via array syntax (e.g. `$_POST['bookings']`), **but** from your VB code, you're actually posting the JSON string as the POST body itself.

In PHP, you can access the raw POST body like this:

```
$bookings = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

The rest of your code should then work as usual.

**Edit:** actually, you've got a typo in there as well. Try

```
$total = count($data['bookings']);
// or
$total = count($data['bookings']['booking']);
```

Comment: thanks @iainn but then how would I access the other parameter (i.e.key)

Comment: It should be in `$data['key']`

Answer (score 1):

There is a json array there also. Try this.

```
<?php
$data='{"key":"91a1522Test",
 "bookings":
   {"booking":[{"ClassId":"4",  "ClassName":"THOASC",   "YearWeek":"1751"}]} }';
$data = json_decode($data,true);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
$total = count($data['bookings']['booking']);
echo $total;
```

Answer (score 1):

> $data = json_decode($bookings,**true**);

Here as per the php documentation sencond argument in json_decode function denotes whether return output as **an object or as an array**

argument 2 = **true** ( will return **array** )

argument 2 = **false** ( will return **object** , it is the default value)

The json_decode produces the following array

```
Array
(
    [key] => 91a1522Test
    [bookings] => Array
        (
            [booking] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [ClassId] => 4
                            [ClassName] => THOASC
                            [YearWeek] => 1751
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Hence it should be accessed like **count($data['bookings']['booking'])**